# What is the approach to draw a 3-port rectangular box with tikz or circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am new to `circuitikz` and `tikz`.

I have spent a few days trying to draw a circuit diagram of a direct conversion IQ transceiver. I am stuck at trying to draw a 3-port rectangular box. For example, the box with the pi/2 in it in the following graph. I searched the user manual but cannot find a three-port device.

[image]

Below is the code I have been experimenting

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{circuitikz}  
\draw
(5,5) node[mixer,box,anchor=east] (m) {}
  to[amp,box,>,-o] ++(2.5,0)
(m.west) node[inputarrow] {} to[short,-o]
    ++(-0.8,0)      
(m.south) node[inputarrow,rotate=90] {} to[twoport,t=90$^{\circ}$] ++(0,-2) 
node[oscillator,box,anchor=north] {};      
\end{circuitikz}   
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: The code example you provided doesn't compile.

Comment: I dont know what is the reason why you cannot compile. I double checked on Sharelatex. It compiled with a single click

Comment: No, even on ShareLatex it doesn't compile (check the "logs and output files" menu). But indeed, after removing `\maketitle` it works. Probably related to me not having updated LaTeX to the newest version on this machine.

Comment: Just use a normal tikz-node and connect it with the anchors north,southm eastm and west. e.g. node[draw]{$\frac{\pi}{2}$}

Comment: You can interpolate between anchors using, for example, `($(node.north west)!.5!(node.west)$)`